# readObject() doesn't read an array

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to create a client-server program where a client sends an array with two objects inside of it to the server. The first object contains just a string. The second object is a shape that the user chooses. The user can choose between 4 different shapes.

1. Rectangle
2. Square
3. Triangle
4. Rombus

So in totale there are 5 classes. Form, Rectangle, Square, Triangle and Rombus. Each shape class inherits from a superclass called "FormaObj". After the client has sent the array to the server, the server has to understand what kind of object the client has sent(Rectangle, Square etc.) and calculate the area and perimeter of that shape.

So let's say for example that i want to send a rectangle to the server.

```
ClientFormeThread2 co;
FormaObj f[];
FormaObj forma;
RettangoloObjThread r;
QuadratoObjThread q;
TriangoloObjThread t;
RomboObjThread ro;
    

    public ClientFormeForm2() {
        initComponents();
        co = new ClientFormeThread2();
        f = new FormaObj[2];
    }

    private void btnRettangoloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    
    try {
            String nome = "Rettangolo";

          //Creating the Obj form
           FormaObj forma = new FormaObj(nome);  

        
         int base = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserire il valore della base")); 
        //Asking the user the insert the value of the base and the height of the rectangle

         int altezza = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserire il valore dell'altezza"));
           
        //Creating the object rectangle
         RettangoloObjThread r = new RettangoloObjThread(base, altezza, nome);   
          
         
         f[0] = forma; //Putting the first object form inside the array
         f[1] = r;  //Putting the second object rectangle inside the array
         
         co.comunicaFormaRettangolo(f); //Sending the array to the server 
         r = co.getRettangolo(); 
       
       atxVisualizza.setText("Rettangolo" + "\n" + "Base: " + r.getLato1()+ "\n" + "Altezza: " + 
        r.getLato2() + "\n" + "Area: " + r.getArea() + "\n" + "Perimetro: " + r.getPerimetro());

       }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientFormeForm2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

That's what's inside **co.comunicaFormaRettangolo(f); //Sending the array to the server**

```
public ClientFormeThread2(){
         try{
            clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8123);
            OutputStream o = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream i = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            outOggetto = new ObjectOutputStream(o);
            inOggetto = new ObjectInputStream(i);
            System.out.println("Client Attivo");     
         }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
                     
     }
  
public void comunicaFormaRettangolo(FormaObj[] forma) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            
            f = forma;
            outOggetto.writeObject(f);
            outOggetto.flush();
            r =(RettangoloObjThread)inOggetto.readObject();
            int Area = r.getArea();
            System.out.println(Area);
          
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            
        }
```

After the server receives the array, it reads what's inside of it.

```
public class ServerFormeThread2 extends Thread{
     Socket clientDaServire;
    int NClient;
    FormaObj f[];
    FormaObj forma;
    RettangoloObjThread r;
    QuadratoObjThread q;
    TriangoloObjThread t;
    RomboObjThread ro;
    ObjectInputStream inOggetto;
    ObjectOutputStream outOggetto;
    

    public ServerFormeThread2(Socket clientDaServire, int NClient) {
        this.clientDaServire = clientDaServire;
        this.NClient = NClient;
    }
    public void run(){
    try{
        OutputStream os = clientDaServire.getOutputStream();
     InputStream ois =  clientDaServire.getInputStream();
      outOggetto = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
      inOggetto = new ObjectInputStream(ois);
      
      f = (FormaObj[]) inOggetto.readObject(); //Reading the array

      String NomeForma = f[0].getMessaggio(); //here i basically get the name of the shape. 
      while(!NomeForma.equals("Disconnetti")){  

          if(NomeForma.equals("Rettangolo")){ //checks whether the value of "NomeForma" equals"Rectangle"
  
              r = (RettangoloObjThread) f[1]; //it reads the rectangle that has been stored inside the array
              r.calcolaAreaRettangolo(); //here it calculates the area

              r.calcolaPerimetroRettangolo(); //and here the perimeter

              outOggetto.writeObject(r);  //and here i only send the object rectangle back to the client because that's what i actually need 

              outOggetto.flush();        
         
          }
          f = (FormaObj[]) inOggetto.readObject(); // i continue listening for other arrays containing 
          shapes that the client might send
          NomeForma = f[0].getMessaggio();
      }
      outOggetto.writeObject(f);
      outOggetto.flush();
      outOggetto.close();
  
        
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

***The Problem***

The first time that an object is sent to the server everything works. So the client receives back the object rectangle and it displays the area and the perimeter on an TextArea. But when i try to send a second array containing another rectangle, the server doesn't read it. The whole program just freezes and i can't do anything apart from closing the server. No error appears. Down below i put the code for the classes "RettangoloObjThread" and "FormaObj"

***RettangoloObjThread***

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class RettangoloObjThread extends FormaObj implements Serializable {

   private int lato1;
   private int lato2;
   private int Area;
   private int Perimetro;
   
   
    public RettangoloObjThread(int lato1, int lato2, String nomeForma) {
        super(nomeForma);
        this.lato1 = lato1;
        this.lato2 = lato2;
        this.Area = 0;
        this.Perimetro = 0;
    }

    

    public int getLato1() {
        return lato1;
    }

    public void setLato1(int lato1) {
        this.lato1 = lato1;
    }

    public int getLato2() {
        return lato2;
    }

    public void setLato2(int lato2) {
        this.lato2 = lato2;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return Area;
    }

    public void setArea(int Area) {
        this.Area = Area;
    }

    public int getPerimetro() {
        return Perimetro;
    }

    public void setPerimetro(int Perimetro) {
        this.Perimetro = Perimetro;
    }
    public void calcolaAreaRettangolo(){
    Area = lato1 * lato2;
}
    public void calcolaPerimetroRettangolo(){
    Perimetro = (lato1 + lato2)*2;
}
    
}
```

***FormaObj***

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

public class FormaObj implements Serializable{
    private String messaggio;

    public FormaObj(String messaggio) {
        this.messaggio = messaggio;
    }

    public String getMessaggio() {
        return messaggio;
    }

    public void setMessaggio(String messaggio) {
        this.messaggio = messaggio;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the client code to send multiple objects? Or are you just hitting a button every time? You're definitely mixing all kinds of code, UI, business logic, sending and  (apparently) multi-threading specific code. That makes it hard if not impossible to test things separately...

Comment: Yes, i hit every time a button.

Comment: There are several reasons that I hate ObjectStream's. First, they only work with Java and if I want to rewrite the server or client in another language, I can't. Second, It's *much* easier to debug text-based protocols. Third, most of the client/server problems I've seen on forums revolve around the use of ObjectStream's.

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your application is frozen, it means that the problem is in the thread deadlock, or an infinite loop is running somewhere, or something is considered very long-determined by the debugger.
   It is also possible that your application simply threw an exception, but it was not logged because it was not handled properly.
2. You can track the problem yourself if you run the applications in debug mode and set breakpoints on the desired lines.
3. To format the code, use Ctrl+Alt+L
   It will be more convenient this way.
4. Be careful with input streams, as they can only be used once.

In any case, running the app in debug mode will help you solve the problem and gain some experience.

Comment: So i've already tried debugging it and figured out that it freezes at the last readObject(). That one that i use to contnue "listening" for another array

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding `writeUnshared()` instead of the normal `write()`